# How to have multiple soft bodies in a single object?

Tags: animation, physics, collision, soft-body

I want to use soft body physics on a human character. It means breasts physics is different than butt, thighs or belly. Is there any way to apply multiple soft bodies on single object? Like vertex groups with separated soft body properties or something : /

Comment: You can create different Vertex Groups for Mass, Goal and Springs. Assign different Weights for different mesh parts to control how much they will be affected by settings.

Comment: Thanks for advice again LukeD! Unfortunately I still don't get how to use it in practice. Weird things happen during experiments, but never what i would like to see. Could you give me an example or something that will help me better understand how it's working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

For the **Soft Body** object I've used two **Vertex Groups**. One for **Goal** and second one for **Springs**. I've assigned different weights for selected parts. You can also draw weights in **Weight Paint** mode.

**Vertex Groups:**

[image]

**Soft Body:**

[image]